# how to replace string which is the key of Json object value Using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

```
const sentence = ' Name: ${fname} ${lname} </br> Email: ${email} </br> ' 

let valuesObj={
  "fname": "sant",
  "lname": "G",
  "email": "Test@test.com"
}
```

tried this code but no use:

```
function replaceAll(str, map){
  for(key in map){
    str = str.replaceAll(key, map[key]);
  }
  return str;
}

var newString = replaceAll(sentence , valuesObj);

console.log(newString)
```

Expected out put is :

Name: sant G

Email:Test@test.com

how to do this Using NodeJs or Javascript

Comment: `sentence = \`Name: ${values.fname} ${values.lname} Email: ${values.email}\``

Comment: hey, I need to replace the ${fname} with Sant dynamically.

Comment: What does it mean to replace dynamically?

Comment: similar to below code 

const replaceManyStr = (values, sentence) => values.reduce((f, s) => `${f}`.replace(values.keys(s)[0], s[values.keys(s)[0]]), sentence)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and clarify it there.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use replace functions here. Do instead:

```js
const valuesObj = {
  fname: 'sant',
  lname: 'G',
  email: 'Test@test.com'
};

const sentence = `Name: ${valuesObj.fname} ${valuesObj.lname} </br> Email: ${valuesObj.email} </br>`;
```

If your string is created dynamically, you are looking for a behavior similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format).

Comment: That's exactly what I described in my comments and OP doesn't want

Comment: I think OP didn't understand your comment despite being right

Comment: I think the variable `sentence` is dynamically read or created.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my answer to add a ref to sprintf-like functions

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the dollar symbol (`$`) and the brackets (`{...}`) in your replace method:

```js
const sentence = ' Name: ${fname} ${lname} </br> Email: ${email} </br> ';

const valuesObj = {
  "fname": "sant",
  "lname": "G",
  "email": "Test@test.com"
};

function replaceAll(str, map) {
  return Object.entries(map).reduce((s, [key, value]) => s.replaceAll(`\${${key}}`, value), str);
}

const newString = replaceAll(sentence, valuesObj);

console.log(newString);
```